# Auto reload list items after deletion (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

**Problem**

I have a view that renders a list of items and provides an option to delete an item. My delete method works well - when I refresh the page manually, the item is gone. But the item list is not reloading automatically after items are deleted.

**Attempted Solution**

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255287/how-to-refresh-vue-components-upon-list-item-removal), I tried adding a `key` attribute of `project`. Since Vue was complaining that the `key` is better to be a string or an integer, I changed the `key` to be `project.id`. However, neither of these solved my problem.

**Template**

```
<el-col :span="8" v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
      <el-card class="project-card">
        <!-- Click to navigate to project -->
        <div @click='navigateProject(project)' class="project-card-inner">
          <!-- Dummy data -->
          <br><em>{{ 'Project ' + project.id }}</em>
        </div>
        <!-- Delete project -->
        <div @click='deleteProject(project)' class="el-icon-delete"></div>
      </el-card>
</el-col>
```

**Script**

```
// under 'methods'
deleteProject(project) {
  this.$confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this project? '
    + 'This cannot be undone.', 'Warning', {
        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        type: 'warning'
      }).then(() => {
        const request_url = this.url + project.id + '/';
        this.$message({
          type: 'success',
          message: 'Project deleted.'
        });
        return axios({
          method: 'delete',
          url: request_url,
          id: project.id
        }).then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }).catch(() => {
        return false;
      })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're only deleting the project on the server and there is no way for Vue to know about this. I would suggest that after you send the axios request you also delete the project in local state. Something like this:

```
deleteProject(project) {
  this.$confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this project? '
    + 'This cannot be undone.', 'Warning', {
        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        type: 'warning'
      }).then(() => {
        const request_url = this.url + project.id + '/';
        this.$message({
          type: 'success',
          message: 'Project deleted.'
        });
        return axios({
          method: 'delete',
          url: request_url,
          id: project.id
        }).then(response => {
          // Logic to delete local state
          const projectIndex = this.projects.findIndex(p => p.id === project.id)
          this.projects.splice(projectIndex, 1)
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }).catch(() => {
        return false;
      })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I saw this in a few solutions but didn't know that it was relevant to my issue, your explanation ("there is no way for Vue to know about this") helped me to understand :)